# Запись в массив ресурсов (Android)

Tags: android, java

В `res\values` есть `xml` файл в нем массив (`string-array`). Как записать в его ячейку значение? Способ

```
final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_pp1s = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.pp1s, android.R.id.list);
adapter_pp1s.insert("12", i);
```

не помогает, хотя

```
adapter_pp1s.getItem(4)
```

возвращает значение.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как записать значение в ячейку массива? Спасибо.

Comment: Зачем? Не встречал ни задач таких, ни проблем. Зачем в файл ресурсов что-то дописывать? Храните данные в бд.

Comment: Недавно занялся программированием. Показалось так проще, чем БД.
Надо хранить 25 значений типа float. Периодически их менять. Пишу что-то типа калькулятора.

Answer (score 2):

Ресурсы в Android все read-only писать туда ничего нельзя.

Скопируйте данные и положите в `Preferences` или SQLite

Comment: Ясно. теперь все стало на свои места)

А можно поподробнее, подскажите где начать копать. Я только месяц как начал изучать яву. До этого была только школа с паскалем.
Спасибо.

Comment: См. сюда: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: И гугл юзай всегда